# Adding a custom ROS package as dependency to another ROS package

Tags: ros, add-dependencies, packages, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS so apologies if it is obvious.
I have multiple ROS packages and currently I use them by linking them to my catkin workspace using symbolic links. What I want to do now is use one CMakeList to call and build the required ROS packages.
I have different ROS actions stored as packages in a folder and I link the main folder to the workspace and I can build it. I can even link each ROS action directory separately and build it. But when I use add_subdirectory in the main cmake file I want to call, it gives me an error that catkin should be listed as a buildtool dependency in package.xml, which it is.

My current folder structure looks like this

```
catkin_ws
--build
--devel
--logs
--src
  --ros_actions
    --action1
      --include
      --src
      --CMakeLists.txt
      --package.xml
    --action2
      --include
      --src
      --CMakeLists.txt
      --package.xml
  --main_file
    --config
    --launch
    --include
    --src
    --CMakeLists.txt
    --package.xml
```

and I want to have something like

```
catkin_ws
--build
--devel
--logs
--src
  --main_file
    --actions
      --action1
        --include
        --src
        --CMakeLists.txt
        --package.xml
      --action2
        --include
        --src
        --CMakeLists.txt
        --package.xml
    --config
    --launch
    --include
    --src
    --CMakeLists.txt
    --package.xml
```

I did try adding "ros_actions" in the CMakelist `include_directories` and `find_package` functions but failed.
Is there a way to add a custom ROS package as a dependency to another?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410286/adding-a-custom-ros-package-as-dependency-to-another-ros-package/) by [A_J](https://answers.ros.org/users/126388/a_j/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know, `catkin_make` does not support **nested** ros packages. But you can put multiple ros-packages in a single directory (i.e. side-by-side, like your ros_actions/.) That top-level directory does not need a CMakeLists.txt file, as catkin_make should discover the ros-packages on its own.

If you change your catkin_ws/src/ directory structure, make sure you do a clean build by deleting catkin_ws/build/ and catkin_ws/devel/ directories.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1